# Docker push: Image depends on an unauthorized parent

Tags: push, commit, docker

Good day!

I have a little problem with pushing my image to docker hub. First of my software versions:

```
vagrant@debian-8-docker:~$ docker version
Client version: 0.11.1
Client API version: 1.11
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): fb99f99
Server version: 0.11.1
Server API version: 1.11
Git commit (server): fb99f99
Go version (server): go1.2.1
vagrant@debian-8-docker:~$
vagrant@debian-8-docker:~$ cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
vagrant@debian-8-docker:~$ uname -a
Linux debian-8-docker 3.14-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.4-1 (2014-05-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
vagrant@debian-8-docker:~$
```

So, first I pull ubuntu image:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu:12.04
```

It rans ok, so I create container and installed ping utility:

```
$ docker run -i ubuntu:12.04 apt-get install -y inetutils-ping
```

After that I commit the changes:

```
$ docker commit -m 'Installed ping utility to ubuntu' -a 'Vasiliy Ozerov' 9a817769bd9a vozerov/ubuntu-ping:v1
```

And tried to push:

```
$ docker push vozerov/ubuntu-ping
The push refers to a repository [vozerov/ubuntu-ping] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository vozerov/ubuntu-ping (1 tags)
511136ea3c5a: Image already pushed, skipping
663644853bf8: Pushing
2014/06/13 19:07:16 HTTP code 400 while uploading metadata: {"error": "Image depends on an unauthorized parent"}
```

docker login was executed successfully:

```
$ docker login
Username (vozerov):
Login Succeeded
```

So I really don't understand what is this.

Please, can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think this might have just started today. I'm having the same issue and came here looking for answers. I pushed basically the same image yesterday with no issues. The only thing I changed was the contents of the working directory and a npm package install.

Answer (score 1):

[Docker System Status](http://status.docker.com/) and [mail thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/gTCUamkhHfA) suggest this is not your fault, but I do not know really.

Comment: Thanks for Docker System Status link and useful information :)