# Docker automated build results in Unexpected failure

Tags: build, docker, auto-build

I am trying to create an automated build with docker. What I have done is linked my bit-bucket repo in the docker hub and trying to build. The status of build is unexpected failure. Also, I see the below failure message:

{"error": "Image depends on an unauthorized parent"}

And interestingly, the logs says build successful.

---

**Failure message**

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: HTTP code 400 while uploading     metadata: {"error": "Image depends on an unauthorized parent"}
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:382:callback
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:490:_startRunCallbacks
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:577:_runCallbacks
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1155:gotResult
    --- <exception caught here> ---
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1097:_inlineCallbacks
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/twisted/python/failure.py:389:throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    /app/builder.py:160:execute_job
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:577:_runCallbacks
    /app/shared/tx/docker.py:295:on_done
    ]
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
# make sure the package repository is up to date
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

# Install vnc, xvfb in order to create a 'fake' display and firefox
RUN apt-get install -y x11vnc xvfb firefox
RUN mkdir /.vnc
# Setup a password
RUN x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd
# Autostart firefox (might not be the best way, but it does the trick)
RUN bash -c 'echo "firefox" >> /.bashrc'

EXPOSE 5900
CMD    ["x11vnc", "-forever", "-usepw", "-create"]
```

**Logs**

```
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu 
Pulling image (quantal) from ubuntu, endpoint: https://cdn-registry-1.docker.io/v1/ e314931015bd
....
.... 
Removing intermediate container c8e48d27a271 
Step 8 : CMD    ["x11vnc", "-forever", "-usepw", "-create"] 
---> Running in d9319762cb0f 
---> bd7eb37a7f78 
Removing intermediate container d9319762cb0f 
Successfully built bd7eb37a7f78
```

Comment: Strange. Can't see anything wrong with this ATM. The only suggestion I have is to try with github if possible, because bitbucket integration is brand new and may have some issues. But that's shooting in the dark...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212543/docker-push-image-depends-on-an-unauthorized-parent) a few days ago may be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: The issue was fixed.**

I just got an answer from the Docker support team. **It's an issue on their side**, which they are already investigating.

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do besides waiting.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the issue?

Comment: No need, the issue seems to be fixed! :)

Comment: Thanks schickling. Yes! its been fixed. Now I am able to build it.